# CheckBox en un JTable - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Como hacer para que al momento que selecciono el checkbox de una fila y seleccione otro checkbox de otra fila se vaya almacenando en una variable y cuando haga click al boton enviar se envie a otra tabla para que sea validado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de creacion de la tabla:

```
tbDocTransferir.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                "C. Costo", "Cod. SD", "Tipo de Archivo", "N\u00B0 Doc.", "Permanencia", "Tipo de Nivel de Archivo", "Per. Ret.", "Solicitar"
            }
        ) {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                Object.class, Object.class, Object.class, Object.class, Object.class, Object.class, Object.class, Boolean.class
            };
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
            boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true
            };
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return columnEditables[column];
            }
        });
        tbDocTransferir.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(93);
        tbDocTransferir.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(87);
        tbDocTransferir.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(125);
        tbDocTransferir.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(95);
        tbDocTransferir.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(150);
        tbDocTransferir.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(92);
        tbDocTransferir.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(61);
        tbDocTransferir.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Mirender());
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tbDocTransferir);
        tbDocTransferir.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        tbDocTransferir.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
```

Este código es para que la informacion que esta en la base de datos se liste en la tabla:

```
void ListarDocumento(String centroCosto){
            ArrayList<ServicioArchivisticoDTO> doc = x.ListarDocumento(centroCosto);
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tbDocTransferir.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
            for (ServicioArchivisticoDTO s : doc){
                Object fila[] = {s.getCentroCosto().getC_t_costo(), s.getSerieDocumental().getC_c_sd(), s.getTipoArchivo().getC_t_tipo_archivo(),
                                    s.getArchivo().getC_t_doc(), s.getSerieDocumental().getN_i_tiempo_retencion()+" años", s.getNivelArchivo().getC_t_nivel_archivo(),
                                    s.getPeriodo_retencion()};
                model.addRow(fila);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace mucho que no utilizo Swing en Java, pero si mal no recuerdo tenes que implementar un listener en el checkbox para poder recuperar el objeto que estas tildando. De ahi lo podrías ir agregando a una lista e ir llenando la otra tabla.
Saludos!

Comment: masomenos una idea de cómo podía implementarlo @SaGiTaRiO

Answer (score 0):

Usando la funcion `TableModelListener`, podrias hacer los siguiente, usando `getRowCount()` para obtener el numero total de filas que hay en tu tabla y `getValueAt()` el cual obtendra el valor en una posicion indicada.

```
//obtenemos el modelos de tu tabla y le agregamos el listener
tbDocTransferir.getModel().addTableModelListener(new checkBoxListener());

public class checkBoxListener implements TableModelListener {

   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int fila = e.getFirstRow();
    int columna = e.getColumn();
    //verifica si la columna es de tipo boolean
    if (columna == BOOLEAN_COLUMN) {
        /*
            obtenemos el modelo de la tabla
            este te servira al igual para obtener los valores de tu tabla,
            dependiendo de la fila y columna que desees tomar.
        */
        TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
        Boolean checked = (Boolean) model.getValueAt(fila, columna);
        //verifica si esta seleccionada
        if (checked) {
            //aqui haces la insercion del registro a una nueva tabla
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Osea lo que quiero hacer es voy seleccionando cada checkbox de cada fila y las filas que esten seleccionadas serán enviadas a otra tabla al momento que le de click a un boton llamado enviar.

Comment: lo que necesitas hacer es un jtablelistener, deja modifico mi respuesta